# Handling multiple data types in Naive Base

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes-classifier

I was studying about NB Classifier and it came out to me that i can use `Bernoulli NB` or `Multinomial NB` for categorical variables but `Gaussian NB` for numeric variables. i have a dataset in which i have a mixture of both.

[image]

**annual_income** is my categoric variable.

I did some research about how to handle it but still i am not very clear. Some options:

1. To fit categorical data with `Bernoulli NB` and numerical data with `Gaussian NB`. After that taking the probabilities using `predict_proba` from both models, fit another model such as Gaussian NB. But as far as i know distribution of data should be gaussian in `Gaussian NB`, but the probabilities from `predict_proba` does not take gaussian distribution.
2. multiply probabilities from `Bernoulli NB` and `Gaussian NB` and predict on the result set.

Which one should be appropriate to use and how they will produce different results? Can i even use these methods?